# Only allowed 100 queries with relatedto?

Tags: limit, query

Despite using null and paginate false i can still only return 100 queries with this:

```
{% set results = craft.entries({
    limit: null,
    paginate: false,
    section: 'directory',
    relatedTo: relationParam
}) %}
```

How do I get all of them?

*** UPDATE ***

Well I found the problem and solution which is a bit strange - makes no sense to me.
I am passing relatedTo a merged string 'relationParam' which has the mulitpple categories I want to search for. Once I set the limits on the categories that are related to the entries -see below - it all works.

```
{% set c = craft.categories.group('locations').slug(countrySlug).limit(null) %}
{% set p = craft.categories.group('locations').slug(portSlug).limit(null) %}
```

So what doesn't make sense to me is that I am having to set the limit outside of the main entries query. I would have thought the entry limit specification would do this  not on the categories related.

Comment: There isn't a `paginate` parameter, so you can safely remove that. Maybe you just happen to have exactly 100 related entries?

Comment: Nah I am expecting 410. I am outputting a count on screen of the results array and its always 100

Comment: What happens if you set the limit parameter to 410? How do you know that there should be 410 entries?

Comment: If I set the limit to 500 I still get just a 100 records returned. If I take out the 'relatedTo' params ( my search query) then I get my 410 records.
It seems that relatedTo params is enforcing a limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is Craft has a default limit of 100 for all ElementCriteriaModel objects (this includes assets, categories, entries, tags, and users, [also relations](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#creating-an-elementCriteriaModel) as you encountered).

This isn't made terribly clear in the documentation, but you can see it under [the defineAttributes() method on the ElementCriteriaModel class reference page](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/ElementCriteriaModel#defineAttributes-detail).

As you discovered, adding a `.limit(null)` parameter overrides that limit.